# Should I stop referring Kali users to U&L from AU?

Tags: discussion, kali

I'm more active on Ask Ubuntu and normally refer Kali users to U&L by telling them:

> We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases **so Kali is off-topic here as well.** However, on [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, especially if you use the *Kali-Linux* tag.  **;-)**

Should I stop referring them here and just post:

> We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases **so Kali is off-topic here as well.**

or continue doing the first one?

### Voting closed a while ago...

... and the AU chat room now shows:

[image: Kali Linux Allowed]

Comment: I'm trying to reconcile this voting conclusion with the current kali-linux tag's "about" statement: "This tag should only be used if your question is _specific_ to Kali Linux. If your question is a general one and you just happen to be using Kali, this tag should not be applied." Should the tag be edited to soften that statement?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: you're better off asking the highest upvoted answer's author then me: I'm mostly AU and very little U&L.

Comment: An alternative would be to tell them to ask their questions on Reddit, or somewhere not SE-related.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

They are, sadly, more appropriate here, seeing the distro is based on a Linux kernel.

In order to minimise the impact on those of us who have little patience for the numbats that think that installing Kali will make them *l337 haXX0r5*, please—as a public service— ensure that they are all tagged [kali-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux) so we can add them to our ignored tag list and thus remain happily oblivious to the bewildering array of ineptitude that consititutes those posts here.<sup>1</sup>

On a personal note, I live in hope that, one day, they have their own StackExchange site where they can happily congregate, breathless with equal amounts of excitement and cluelessness, and their adolescent ardour for penetration is finally able to be appreciated by the audience it deserves.

<sup>1. This has been my own crusade for some significant time now, and I would welcome more hands to the pump...</sup>

Comment: I'll adapt my message!  Done!  You didn't forget to vote I hope?

Comment: +1, that made be laugh so hard :') Maybe we could consider sending them to Security Stack Exchange sometimes, I don't see why we should be the only ones suffering... After all, they have the tag too, on 95 questions. See also :http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86353/hackoverflow

Comment: Notice, there are issues that don't have anything to do with the fact that the user is using Kali Linux (ie. shell usage, gnome, apt, etc.). The rule of thumb is: if you can't blame kali, nor the user, it may be a good question.

Comment: @Braiam a.k.a unicorn!

Comment: @jasonwryan Ahem. Regarding line 1: They are more appropriate here, seeing the distro is not *an official derivative of Ubuntu*. AU doesn't care whether they based it off Ubuntu or Debian, but only whether it's listed in with the derivatives mentioned [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). Just commenting to clarify for anyone who might read it and think being based on Ubuntu might make them on-topic on AU.

Comment: 6+15 = 21 Black jack!  I'll have someone post this on the chat wall in AU.

Comment: I've flagged this post because of that last line ("flowery and suggestive prose").  You do know about [the carrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offensive_Security_Certified_Professional)?  It is not free as in beer either.

Comment: @goldilocks I wasn't aware that flowery and suggestive prose was verboten here...

Comment: Yes.  We has all your bases.

Comment: Jason: you should have tons of hands helping you at the pump by now...  Dry yet???  **;-)**

Comment: The tag description says: "If your question is a general one and you just happen to be using Kali, this tag should not be applied." So it is not appropriate to systematically have them all tagged [tag:kali-linux].

Comment: @JohnWHSmith Do NOT send them to [security.se]. The Kali Linux questions I see on [unix.se] are almost always newbie administration or usage questions. The Kali Linux questions I see on [security.se] are often administration or usage questions as well, and they are off-topic on Sec.SE.

Comment: @Gilles Unfortunately... I was sharing jasonwryan's hope of an independent community as well, but the Hack Overflow proposal was recently closed as "not a viable proposal" on Area51. [Another proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90597/codebreakers-codehackers-hackoverflow) was made 2 days ago but it doesn't seem to cover the same scope, and is, to me, just as unlikely to be seen as "viable".

Comment: Any objections to softening the current kali-linux tag description, then? It is currently in opposition to this accepted answer.

Comment: Wrote a man who gives users arrogant replies like that https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2068918#p2068918 .

Answer (score 17):

Kali *is* a *nix distribution! Keep the script-kiddies coming!

Comment: I mean, it pretty clearly *is* a distro, although I don't entirely understand all the terrible Kali questions we've been seeing lately

Comment: @MichaelMrozek It's a gateway drug.

Answer (score 15):

Please. Please! PLEASE! Keep those Kali questions *away from here!*

Comment: Split personality syndrome? Anyway, upvoted.

Comment: Kali is as evil as it sounds