# Someone interested in an openSUSE SE?

Tags: discussion

I'm a openSUSE Linux user, and I would be interested in a SE site for this distro in the same fashion of AskUbuntu; I know that there is already "Unix & Linux", but it seems focused more on general distro-agnostic knowledge (its top tags are `linux`, `bash`, `shell-script`, and so on), more focused on Linux itself (shell and CLI) and less on daily usage of distros.

I've created a [proposal on Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113962/opensuse), and I'd like to know if other users here would be interested to back it up.

Comment: We have several other Linux distributions represented here, with their distro-specific questions; hopefully you don't think SUSE is off-topic here?

Comment: The tags should not be used only to identify the distro the person asking the question happens to be using. So don't take the number of questions tagged with SuSe as an indication of how many SuSe questions we have or how welcome SuSe is here. It is absolutely welcome. Personally, I am *very* strongly against distro-specific sites. They're on topic here, why make a new one?

Comment: By the way, if you're mean [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113962/opensuse) it has already bee closed as a duplicate of U&L.

Comment: There's really no reason for individual SE sites for the different distros. Ubuntu is a exception to this given the sheer amount of "newb" questions it generates, beyond that U&L can cover all distros of *nix.

Answer (score 5):

I proposed to open a Red Hat SE some time ago, but the proposal was not accepted. The reason (which makes sense after all) is that it would be a duplicate of Unix&Linux. So I don't think openSUSE stands better chances.

Comment: A Kali Linux SE. on the other hand, would be [an excellent idea](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3605/6761)...