# Systematically closing Kali questions

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, reopen-closed, kali

When I asked the reviewer who originally posted the duplicate link why he was duping [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403253/apt-get-command-not-found-in-kali-linu), he referred me to this Meta post: [What should we do about Kali Linux questions?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4640/what-should-we-do-about-kali-linux-questions). In the top-upvoted answer it says "I do not propose systematically closing Kali questions!". Although the question has an accepted answer, it was marked as a duplicate of a question that is not specific to the question that was asked, and then it was (incorrectly??) closed.

Comment: Yes, things are not as intended.  At https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403220/ for example, the questioner is accused by five people of being "another noob kali user", even though the question is actually a fairly reasonable one, relating to Kali's switch to a rolling release system and actually called out in Kali's repository doco.  At another question a now deleted similar comment about "noob kali user" gave such offence to the questioner that the xe was quite angry and then, in Kafkaesque fashion, chastised by StackExchange people for not "being nice" to someone who _insulted xem_.

Comment: Collaboratively built is Stack Exchange sugar for a frequent reviewer like me because there is so much built-in potential for improvement.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<del>No, I agree that one shouldn't have been closed. This is a surprising change since `apt-get` has been the standard for many years and even experienced users might have been blindsided by it.</del>

I had completely misunderstood the situation. I thought that Debian and, by extension Kali, no longer used `apt-get` and only shipped with `apt`. I thought this was a new change and, therefore, would indeed surprise many users. As was [explained to me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41022644#41022644) that's nonsense, `apt-get` is part of the `apt` package and the only way to have one without the other is via some sort of PEBKAC.

Nevertheless, while I can understand closing that question as non-reproducible or too broad or unclear (as some of the close voters had indeed chosen to do), I don't think that one was a valid duplicate of the broad "Kali is not for newbs" question since it was a specific problem and actually answerable.

So, I have reopened the question and would like to take this opportunity to ask the community not to automatically close in favor of the "Kali is hard" question. We should only use that as a dupe target when the issue is obviously that the OP is new to Linux and really shouldn't be using Kali *because* they are new to Linux.

Comment: ... what is the change here from the standard? If you're talking about the apt command, it looks like OP didn't have apt installed at all (the answer is suggesting manually installing the apt package, after all). If not having apt installed is standard on Kali, then isn't this a textbook example of a clueless user starting on Kali without knowing anything about it?

Comment: @muru nothing whatsoever, I had completely misunderstood the issue. See updated answer.

Comment: @roaima nope, still open.

Comment: I'm not sure why Kali is any "harder" or "not newb friendly" then the underlying Debian. I find that Debian advice applies to Kali 99% of the time.