# Quick answer for "I need someone to make me a script that does <x>"

Tags: discussion, review

This is different from questions for software suggestions.

Those are questions for scripting in the answer, almost like a *commission* to have someone write a shell script or use some other scripting language to do a little text processing, or similar.

I've come across a great many of those sorts of questions lately, and I was wondering if we could have a pre-made text-chunk for reviewing questions. I usually use my own little copy-paste text that this website isn't for commissions, and you should at least try to solve the problem, etc. I also sometimes point to other SE websites.

Should I just be using my copy-paste approach, or should I do something else? And if it's the correct way, could we have a one-click solution for that when making reviews? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Related: "Write my code for me" in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments

Comment: Now that I think about this, I'm kinda on the fence with it. Assuming someone would bounty a 10k question like that, I'd write the shell script in no time, but then again, I don't think unix.SE is the correct website for that. Might be a good idea for another SE site. I.e. Where asking questions is actually down to asking for code, in the "code this and that for me, pls".

Comment: Should it be forbidden to answer such questions? It depends on how one responds. If I write an in-depth and exciting answer, pointing out pitfalls and error conditions, it may benefit others, no? Or do you see answers as only being for the users that ask the questions?

Comment: @they I think simply asking for code (especially on **unix**.SE) is just not the right place to do so. I think questions for that should perhaps go on a specific site for "code commissions" or something. In general I'm not against it, but I don't think unix.SE is the correct place for it, etc.

Comment: Off-the-cuff thoughts: it seems to me that we have two sets of users -- those who want to see useful, well-written questions with demonstrated effort and those that want to be rewarded with reputation points by answering any question that they're able to. There's overlap between the sets, too! Stack Exchange (IMHO) covers both situations. Short of an answer at this point, but I'm thinking if you see a question that "does not show any research effort, is unclear, or is not useful" then consider voting-to-close and/or downvoting.

Comment: @JeffSchaller hmm, ok, so basically what I've been doing so far, with the comment I used, too.

Comment: Is there room for a third group of users, please? The group of users that wants to see self-contained and well-written answers that are general enough to be helpful to others yet still specific enough to address the original poster's needs? The knowledge-sharing group? Belonging to this group, I'd like to answer even the "gimme the code" type of questions.

Comment: I jumped to conclusions when reading this Question and assumed it was describing the common homework-type question of "make this turn into that" with no effort shown. I'm personally happy to see well-written questions (and answers) on the site. Certainly, every question on this site is a request for someone else to do work -- to figure out *a* way to solve the problem or to describe how the OP's way failed, and/or both.

Comment: So, are you asking: can someone write me a script to automatically review the "write me a script" questions?

Comment: I tend to analize what is the *minimum* effort put into the question. I never downvote *except* the copy pasted homework assignments. It's just people that think the site *is a scripting service*. Then there is the next level, at least the OP wrote they own words, but doesn't show any work done by they part. At least in these situations, *you can ask for it*, and they would maybe share some code. They may just need a little push.

Comment: → So with more interaction, you can make a VLQ question a passable and answerable one.

Comment: I answer such questions sometimes - when i think the problem is interesting (or a good opportunity to showcase a useful technique) AND the OP doesn't come across as being demanding.  I'm inclined to write such answers for the general reader and only incidentally solve the OP's problem while doing so.

Comment: Historically attempts to write shared stock responses have got a little out of hand. eg: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5316/why-i-closed-the-why-is-kali-so-hard-question