# What is the cause of the Kali phenomenon?

Tags: discussion, kali

[Recent discussions](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4640/52236) talk about the phenomenon. My this question tries to make clear its reason.

Thus, this question isn't about, what we have to do with the Kali questions. This question is about *what social/psychological/cultural/... phenomenon creates them*.

Where are they from? Why they've chosen Kali?

What drives so many "young titans" to start to use such a not-for-beginners distribution? I think, likely something misleaded them, and if they've known, what is waiting them, they'd likely remained by some more common, more desktop-tuned, Ubuntu/Suse/anything line.

I am curious also to the answers from the "other side", i.e. people whose Kali questions were closed, probably too quickly on his opinion.

---

Extension: [@muru](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) [refers](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4722/what-is-the-cause-of-the-kali-phenomenon?noredirect=1#comment8281_4722) a [comment](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4640/what-should-we-do-about-kali-linux-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment8084_4640) about a phenomenon, there a search engine effect was suggested. However, the posters have very similar characteristic (for example: bad English, newbie questions, trying to use Kali as a beginner desktop variant and so on). A search engine effect would result much more diverse OPs.

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4640/what-should-we-do-about-kali-linux-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment8084_4640

Comment: @FaheemMitha Knowing them better would help a lot to effectively deal with them. For example, the post linked by Muru suggests that it is a simple search engine effect. I don't think that it would be so, because the posters have very similar characteristic (for example: bad English, nickname sounding like Indian, newbie questions, trying to use Kali as a beginner desktop variant and so on). A search engine effect would result much more diverse OPs.

Comment: @peterh I'm a little sceptical about their being a strong Indian connection. Yes, Kali sounds Indian, and is the name of an Indian goddess. But I am not convinced that leads to large numbers of Indians using it. And let's suppose they do. So what? There is already a recent question (created by Gilles) which we can point people to when they come here asking clueless Kali questions. Though I realise it isn't intended as a catch-all.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Ok, but the question is, what is the reason then?

Comment: @peterh What's the reason for what?

Comment: @FaheemMitha The cause of the Kali problem. The essence of the question.

Comment: @peterh If by problem you mean the large number of clueless people who are attempting to use Kali, it's been discussed in various places already, and I have no more idea than anyone else. And I doubt there is a solution to this "problem", either. Short of shutting down Kali.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I removed that part of the post, although I don't think there had been any bad in it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kali is specifically targetted at <s>h</s>crackers as the title of their web page states:

> Kali Linux: Penetration testing and ethical hacking Linux Distribution

Kali attracts wannabe crackers. Adolescent boys, generally, enthralled by the idea of penetration (*paging Dr Freud*). Not only are they clueless about Linux, they have little awareness about anything beyond the realms of their fetid bedrooms and the online communities where they congregate to boast about their leet skillz.

So, not only are you wrong; you are very wrong. This has nothing to do with ethnicity; the common denominator here is idiocy, an attribute that is evenly distributed amongst all populations. Sadly for us, it just has a vector for expression here.

Comment: @peterh Yeah, except your entire third and fourth paragraphs...

Comment: I belong to the ones wanting to *save* the Kali questions, and opposing the whole anti-kali policy. My opinion was always that if a question is bad, then it should be closed because it is bad, but no question should be ever closed because it is about Kali. My [review history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52236/peterh?tab=activity&sort=reviews) is public and it shows that probably very clearly. But this post is not about that, here I only wanted to understand the background.

Comment: I removed that part of the post, although I don't think there had been any bad in it.

Comment: @peterh There is no "anti-kali policy". There is a bad question policy and there is a high correlation (for reasons outlined multiple times here and on the main site) between bad questions and [tag:kali-linux]. For the reasons I touched on in my answer, that is unlikely to change.

Comment: Many Kali questions were closed, and now deleted, *"because of Kali"*. There were [strong suggestions](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4640/52236) to expel Kali from the site, and the *de facto* behavior of the reviewers was that Kali questions got a quick end.

Comment: But: yes, the ratio of the bad questions in the case of the Kali are significantly higher, but it doesn't reason any different treatment. It reasons to think about its probable cause.

Comment: @peterh The probable cause is no mystery. Read my answer. Muppets are attracted to Kali like morons to reality TV...

Comment: @peterh I have done it.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I also believe there are a common thread between some ethnicities and bad questions. Not all cultures have the same work ethic, or worries about writing perfect things. However, without the OP country not being displayed in posts, this belongs to the realm of speculation.

Comment: My guess - Mr.Robot made this distro so popular. :)