# Arch Linux vs Kali Linux

Tags: discussion

I earlier using Kali Linux. I asked lot of questions with [kali-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux) tag. I had read [the answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/449077).

> Linux isn't hard but, kali is.

I noticed that I could use Kali more smoothly. When I was trying to install [arch-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arch-linux). I notice that it is very hard to install [arch-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arch-linux). So, why people says that `Kali is hard`? While I get [kali-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux)  very smooth. I had only 10% knowledge of Linux that's why I had to ask very beginner type questions. Even, I left [arch-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arch-linux) in a day cause, it was very harder. As I said I don't have much more knowledge of Linux that's why I am writing the question. While [arch-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arch-linux) is harder than why peoples are responding to arch questions not Kali's? So, arch is also for professionals. Most of users are ignoring Kali's questions but, not Arch's why?

Comment: Installing Arch is hard, Arch is also not designed for new users. However, _using_ Arch is the same as any other normal Linux while Kali is not.

Comment: I'd be careful with "foo is hard" statements. Installing (and administering) Arch is probably harder than installing some friendlier distributions, but it becomes quite easy once you realize that a detailed [guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide) exists and take the time (and patience) to read through all the relevant pages. On the other hand, Arch (which, by the way, is not mentioned in the quoted answer) doesn't target the average user; rather, it tends to work best for those willing to take the point of view of a distribution developer.

Comment: _"why peoples are responding to arch questions not Kali's?"_: what did suggest you that? Out of 2019 [tag:kali-linux] questions, 410 are [unanswered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bkali-linux%5D+is%3Aq+answers%3A0) (~20.3 %); that figure is 917/4011 (~22.9 %) for [tag:arch-linux]. Even looking at the 50 most recent questions (right now) (basically unaffected by the automatic cleanup of >30 days old closed and non-closed, negatively-scored questions), 23 of those tagged Kali have at least one answer, compared to 20 in the case of Arch.

Comment: People aren't *ignoring* Kali questions, as you put it, and preferring to answer Arch questions.  People answer the questions to which they have an answer.

Comment: @Chenmunka No people doesn't answer "the question" which they can answer... Cause, when I was using Linux Mint i had face an issue then, everyone solved that. While when I faced the same issue Kali no one came to answer my question...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hesitate to post this as an Answer, because I don't have any direct experience with Kali (or with Arch Linux, for that matter), so I'm not the target audience here. That won't stop me from speculating a bit, though.

Beyond fra-san's point in the comment about the unanswered percentages being similar (I see ranges from ~28% for Debian, to ~35% for both Kali and Arch, to ~36% for Ubuntu), I think Kali users had a rough start at Stack Exchange. In 2015, when we [accepted their redirection from Ask Ubuntu](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3602/117549), there were already worrying signs: "so we can add them to our ignored tag list" and "I don't entirely understand all the terrible Kali questions we've been seeing lately". I see there are nearly twice as many deleted Kali questions than deleted Arch questions.

The story continued, with [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/117549), saying "Kali Linux is a distribution for professional penetration testers who are already very familiar with Linux" and [What should we do about Kali Linux questions?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4640/117549), saying "It's well-known that we have a quality problem in the kali-linux tag" and [Splash screen test for kali-linux questions](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4829/splash-screen-test-for-kali-linux-questions) and [Why are Kali questions hated so much?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5257/why-are-kali-questions-hated-so-much), and finally with [Yet another Kali Discussion (Working Title)](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5530/117549) saying "I wonder if we can find a way, as a community, to direct people away from Kali without telling them "Kali is great!" and without requiring such opinionated responses".

I think what happened is that we got an influx of poorly-asked questions which then got downvoted, closed, and/or deleted, and also (I suspect) caused many users (potential Answerers) to ignore the tag.

Comment: I was using Kali for a long while. I started Debian. I noticed there was lot of problem I was facing in Debian. I wasn't familiar with those problems also. So, I left Debian. I noticed most of Kali users including faces wireless connection problem. Few days some commented in a post that one of Kali documentation is saying that there's some problem wireless connection. I don't remember the accurate documentation. I searched a lot but, I didn't find. Arch is lot more harder than Kali. Cause, Arch isn't based on Debian. In my view, I didn't find any difference between Ubuntu and Kali.

Comment: Kali is only best for Pen-testing, I understood when I moved to Fedora. I am keep searching for wireless connection problem in Kali(Why this happens to all peoples?). Even, when I talk to professional Kali users. They don't reply. I don't know why. That's why I left Kali. In this community some people says,"While you are using Kali you shouldn't ask this question." I request to moderators to review this kind of comments. Kali users don't get help. Even, I was having issue with mailing. They said,"You are using Kali you shouldn't ask this." That's why I asked the question.